# (symfony 1.4) Add an option in a Widget

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have to add the option 'with_empty' like sfWidgetFormFilterInput in a sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice. I know this option is not available with this widget but i have to add it, but i don't know how do to do it.

```
class TrainingFormFilter extends BaseTrainingFormFilter
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['tracks_list']
      ->setOption('order_by', array('name', 'ASC'))
      ->setOption('multiple', false)
      ->setOption('add_empty', true);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it you are trying to achieve?

`add_empty` is available in the `DoctrineChoice` and `with_empty` is available in the `Filter`